# Using two separate sqlite databases in one android app via Ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

For the purpose of maximum portability, I would like to maintain two different sqlite databases in one android app using OrmLite. However, it seems that once Context is given, the OpenHelperManager.getHelper() returns only one of the two helpers and throw IllegalStateException:

Any way to get around it?